# How to read javascript file using HttpWebRequest in c#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I have a javascript file in a remote server, and when I use httpwebrequest it returns some weird characters.

Thr url is http://goo.gl/0Ug5QI

Is this kind of compressed contents?

```
static string GetScriptSource(string _url)
{
    string _retValue = string.Empty;

    HttpWebRequest hwr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
    hwr.Method  = "GET";

    HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)hwr.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());

    return sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

My code to read that script file's content is very simple.

Comment: The link you posted is redirected to an url using https, thats why you cannot get the plain text, the text is encrypted. [https](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure)

Comment: @MihaiHantea Thx for your answer. Do you mean it is encrypted by SSL? But I think it's not that easy. Coz, I've already decrypted that protocol using wireshark based on http://security14.blogspot.kr/2010/07/how-to-use-fiddler-and-wireshark-to.html. Although, I got the decrypted stream it returns those weird characters.

Comment: What encoding are you using?

Comment: @MihaiHantea Well, I have tried 140 codepages from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx. But none of them works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the js source that you linked to, it could be that is has been gzipped. Try saving the source as a file and use 7zip or something to see if you can unzip it. There is a GZip library in C# so if it has been gzipped then you should be able to unzip it easily enough.

Although it's a Korean web site so maybe the encoding is not correct.

Either way it's not a problem with the code that you posted.

Comment: Yes you are right about the code. I tried using the GZip library in C# and is not working, exception: "The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream." maybe is using different app to archive it. Winrar is not working also.

Comment: I'm out of ideas then. Is there a web site that uses that javascript file that you can point me to?

Comment: @AdamValpied I have also tried to download the script file and replace the extension as .zip, .rar, .gz and .tar. None of them working right.  Are there some compression algorithm that I can read about?

Comment: From what I understand gzip is the only compression algorithm that can be used for js files. My guess is that it's an encoding issue, or the file is not a valid js file. Have you seen this being used somewhere?

Comment: @AdamValpied Yes, there is an java application using that java script. And the java application can read that correctly. I think that's because the web site is written in java.